# Excel - self adjusting chart marker

Tags: excel, charts

I have a series of line graphs in excel that is data over time.
There are several date milestones in the chart (I.E. Nov 24th: Black Friday)

On the chart I'm trying to put in an arrow on the chart with the label over the chart near the date. (See attached, below)

The problem is that these are manually added and as I expand the data in the chart (add another month of data) the chart compresses and my milestone markers have to all be hand repositioned.

How can I do these milestone markers so that I don't have to hand edit the table every time I expand the chart? A sample chart with a column for the desired labels can be found at [this link](http://www.lordandrei.com/Media/Sample_Issue.xlsx).

As an added note, I'm using Office (Excel) 11 for Mac.

[image: Example of a milestone marker on the chart]

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use data labels for the milestones?  There is a nice article about using a formula to make a custom data label:
http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/05/change-data-labels-in-charts/

Answer (score 0):

Make your arrow and label outside the chart. Plot a new series with one point, with X corresponding to the date and Y determined appropriately (as I'll describe in a moment).

Copy the shapes you want to use as a milestone, select the point you added above, and paste (Ctrl+V).

Now adjust the Y value for this point so the milestone is where you want it.

This tutorial shows a similar approach:
[Use an Arrow to Indicate Special Points](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/PointAtPoints.html)